# Hide dynamically created element (php and html) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, hide, show

I have a div that retrieves data from database with PHP and attach the info to html elements.

```
<?php
$product_array = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct ORDER BY id ASC");
if (!empty($product_array)) { 
    foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){
?>
    <div class="product-item">
        <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>"></div>
            <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
            <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
```

I have 3 different input numbers (grs, kgs, pzas) and a dropdownlist to select which one should be used.

```
<div class="cantidad">
                <input class="medida" id="grs" type="number" name="gramos" step="50" value="50" size="1" min="50" max="950" onkeydown="return false" />
                <input class="medida" id="kgs" type="number" name="kilogramos" step=".5" value=".5" size="2" min=".5" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
                <input class="medida" id="pzas" type="number" name="unidades" step="1" value="1" size="2" min="1" max="99"onkeydown="return false"  />
                <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="medidas()">
                    <option value="grs">grs</option>
                    <option value="kgs">kgs</option>
                    <option value="pzas">pzas</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

And I have tried hidding the other 2 input numbers with javascript but is not working as desired.

```
$( function() {
                $('#cd-dropdown').dropdown();
            });

        function medidas()
        {
            var tipo = document.getElementById('cd-dropdown').value;
            if(tipo=='grs')
            {
                document.getElementById('grs').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('kgs').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('pzas').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else if(tipo=='kgs')
            {
                document.getElementById('grs').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('kgs').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('pzas').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            else if(tipo=='pzas')
            {
                document.getElementById('grs').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('kgs').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('pzas').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
```

What I want is the user can select one option from the list and then the right input should be visible while the other 2 should be hidden.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuS4F.png)

Comment: Any special reason why you're not using jQuery for this? You already have it available and you're using it for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the `onchange` attribute of the dropdown. The event handler will be added via [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

This also uses some ES6 "magic" ([`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), [arrow functions (`=>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from))

```js
let select = document.querySelector("#cd-dropdown"),
    inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cantidad>input.medida"));

select.addEventListener("change", medidas, false);
medidas.call({ "value": select.value });  // "fake" a change event

function medidas(e) {
  inputs.forEach(i => {
    i.style.visibility = (i.id === this.value ? "visible" : "hidden");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="cantidad">
  <input class="medida" id="grs" type="number" name="gramos" step="50" value="50" size="1" min="50" max="950" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida" id="kgs" type="number" name="kilogramos" step=".5" value=".5" size="2" min=".5" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida" id="pzas" type="number" name="unidades" step="1" value="1" size="2" min="1" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
      <option value="grs">grs</option>
      <option value="kgs">kgs</option>
      <option value="pzas">pzas</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Update**

"*but it changes all the inputs in all the products*"

So there are multiple `<div class="cantidad">...</div>` elements?
Then you have to change the ids to classes because ids have to be unique.

```js
let selects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cd-select"));

selects.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener("change", medidas, false);
  medidas.call(select); // "fake" a change event
});

function medidas() {
  let inputs = Array.from(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll("input.medida"))

  inputs.forEach(i => {
    i.style.visibility = (i.classList.contains(this.value) ? "visible" : "hidden");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="cantidad">
  <input class="medida grs" type="number" name="gramos" step="50" value="50" size="1" min="50" max="950" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida kgs" type="number" name="kilogramos" step=".5" value=".5" size="2" min=".5" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida pzas" type="number" name="unidades" step="1" value="1" size="2" min="1" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <select class="cd-select">
    <option value="grs">grs</option>
    <option value="kgs">kgs</option>
    <option value="pzas">pzas</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="cantidad">
  <input class="medida grs" type="number" name="gramos" step="50" value="20" size="1" min="50" max="950" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida kgs" type="number" name="kilogramos" step=".5" value=".2" size="2" min=".5" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <input class="medida pzas" type="number" name="unidades" step="1" value="2" size="2" min="1" max="99" onkeydown="return false" />
  <select class="cd-select">
    <option value="grs">grs</option>
    <option value="kgs">kgs</option>
    <option value="pzas">pzas</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it changes all the inputs in all the products, is it possible to manipulate them individually?

Comment: @g4b0.88 I've updated my answer because of your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($(".medida"), function() {
    $(this).prop("hidden", $(this).prop("id") != tipo);
})
```

You want to **hide** the element, which is setting an HTML attr, which is different of setting up the CSS `visibility` property.

*EDIT*: Thanks to @Andreas for pointing out the wrong selector.

*EDIT2*: Change the code for dynamic `hidden` input.

Comment: [hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp) is a global HTML attr, so all elements have it. It should use `hidden` as he/she **don't want to show the rest of the options** because, as the link says, `When present, it specifies that an element is not yet, or is no longer, relevant`. Also, `visibility` makes the element invisible, but it will take space yet (`Even invisible elements take up space on the page`), which can be ugly sometimes.

Comment: Ups, wrong understanding, thinked that where the `options`, thanks, editing right now